# Slow performance of basic Parse server queries

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

We have parse server using postgresql as database. Problem is it runs simple queries extremely slow compared to sql or running them from js via pg.
For example getting all users (~5k rows in table) takes couple of seconds. Getting sessions and users takes from 3 seconds up to in extreme cases 8-10. Example:

```
 let Session = Parse.Object.extend("_Session");
 let sessionQuery = new Parse.Query(Session);
 sessionQuery.include("user");
 sessionQuery.limit(100000);
 let sessions = await sessionQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true });
```

This segment runs slow 2-3 seconds, sometimes up to 8, while running sql is 100ms or so. There are only ~5k users and 9k sessions. We tried setting direct access variable, we checked that its indeed properly set inside parseServer.js source. Currently we are moving all select type queries to SQL but it would be preferable to find solution.

Comment: Could you share more details on how you performed the comparison test?